# Oracle index with I_JS$ in name

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

After upgrade of Oracle to version 19
database started adding index named `I_JS$XXXX` on creation od materialized view `XXXX`

this created index blocks creation of our index on that field
do anyoune know why oracle is creating this index ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, in your DB is  "automatic indexing" turned on.

As variant of solution(local) of this query/problem:

```
   begin
     dbms_auto_index.drop_auto_indexes(
       owner          => 'YOUR_SCHEMA',
       index_name     => 'YOUR AUTO_INDEX',
       allow_recreate => false);
   end;
   /
```